# Missing data when creating report with DynamicJasper

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

has anyone had problems with words missing when using dynamicJasper? 
More detail on problem is this:
Let say that in certain field i want to print out rather large String: "HOUSE NUMBER"

so if width for that column is set to 30, it is printed out fine,

**if it is set to 20 only HOUSE is printed out** and

if it is set to 15 both words are printed, but in two rows, which is also fine.

I don't know how can i avoid this problem, if there are many different "Strings" in certain column and no matter what width is set, there is always something missing.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting isStretchWithOverFlow(boolean) as true?